# How to draw a random triangle and its median?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I want to draw a triangle like this:

[image]

I have tried different ways of solving it, but I have not done it correctly. How to add median lines in the triangle? Could someone please help and explain this to me?

```
from turtle import *
import random

def allTriMedian (w=300):
    speed (0)
    vertices = []
    point = turtle.Point(x,y)

    for i in range (3):
        x = random.randint(0,300)
        y = random.randint(0,300)
        vertices.append(trutle.Point(x,y))
        point = turtle.Point(x,y)
        triangle = turtle.Polygon(vertices)

    a = triangle.side()
    b = triangle.side() 
    c = triangle.side()  
    m1 = tirangle.median
    m2 = triangle.median
    m3 = triangle.median
```

I tried to put the equation directly

```
def Median (a, b, c):
    m1 = sqrt((((2b^2)+(2c^2)-(a^2))))
    m2 = sqrt((((2a^2)+(2c^2)-(b^2))))
    m3 = sqrt((((2a^2)+(2b^2)-(c^2))))
    triangle.setFill("yellow")
    triangle.draw(allTriMedian)
```

Or I thought to find a midpoint and draw a line segment to connect the vertices and midpoints.

```
def getMid(p1,p2):
      return ( (p1[0]+p2[0]) / 2, (p1[1] + p2[1]))
      mid1 = Line((point(p1[0]+p2[0]) / 2),point(x))
      mid2 = Line((point(p2[1]+p3[1]) / 2),point(y))
```

Comment: your code does not have valid indentation, please use the `{}` format button in the markdown editor.  Also StackOverflow is a place for general programming questions, explaining this specific code to you would not be useful to future readers so this question is off topic.

Comment: Even if it was on topic, I'm not sure explaining the solution to you in the manner you want will really help you.  A huge part of programming is about problem solving - even if you don't know how to write the code to do what you want you should at least be able to figure out an algorithm to describe the process of how to solve the problem, then once you have that you can put it into code.

Answer (score 2):

I hate doing math.  Let's see if we can solve this by throwing turtles at the problem.  Lots of turtles.

We'll randomly generate the verticies of the triangle.  Taking pairs of verticies in turn, we'll start a turtle at each heading toward the other.  When the turtles collide (at the midpoint), we'll eliminate one turtle and send the other toward the vertex not in the pair.  Once we've done this three times (with six turtles), we should have the drawing in question.  Well, mostly (no fill in my solution):

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen
from random import seed, randint

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 640, 480

def meet_in_the_middle(turtle_1, turtle_2):

    position_2 = turtle_2.position()

    while True:
        turtle_1.setheading(turtle_1.towards(turtle_2))
        turtle_1.forward(1)
        position_1 = turtle_1.position()
        if int(position_1[0]) == int(position_2[0]) and int(position_1[1]) == int(position_2[1]):
            break

        turtle_2.setheading(turtle_2.towards(turtle_1))
        turtle_2.forward(1)
        position_2 = turtle_2.position()
        if int(position_2[0]) == int(position_1[0]) and int(position_2[1]) == int(position_1[1]):
            break

seed()

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(WIDTH * 1.25, HEIGHT * 1.25)

vertices = []

for _ in range(3):
    x = randint(-WIDTH//2, WIDTH//2)
    y = randint(-HEIGHT//2, HEIGHT//2)
    vertices.append((x, y))

A, B, C = vertices

turtle_AtoB = Turtle(shape='turtle')
turtle_AtoB.penup()
turtle_AtoB.goto(A)
turtle_AtoB.pendown()

turtle_BtoA = Turtle(shape='turtle')
turtle_BtoA.penup()
turtle_BtoA.goto(B)
turtle_BtoA.pendown()

meet_in_the_middle(turtle_AtoB, turtle_BtoA)

turtle_BtoA.hideturtle()
turtle_AtoB.setheading(turtle_AtoB.towards(C))
turtle_AtoB.goto(C)
turtle_AtoB.hideturtle()


turtle_BtoC = Turtle(shape='turtle')
turtle_BtoC.penup()
turtle_BtoC.goto(B)
turtle_BtoC.pendown()

turtle_CtoB = Turtle(shape='turtle')
turtle_CtoB.penup()
turtle_CtoB.goto(C)
turtle_CtoB.pendown()

meet_in_the_middle(turtle_BtoC, turtle_CtoB)

turtle_CtoB.hideturtle()
turtle_BtoC.setheading(turtle_BtoC.towards(A))
turtle_BtoC.goto(A)
turtle_BtoC.hideturtle()


turtle_CtoA = Turtle(shape='turtle')
turtle_CtoA.penup()
turtle_CtoA.goto(C)
turtle_CtoA.pendown()

turtle_AtoC = Turtle(shape='turtle')
turtle_AtoC.penup()
turtle_AtoC.goto(A)
turtle_AtoC.pendown()

meet_in_the_middle(turtle_CtoA, turtle_AtoC)

turtle_AtoC.hideturtle()
turtle_CtoA.setheading(turtle_CtoA.towards(B))
turtle_CtoA.goto(B)
turtle_CtoA.hideturtle()

screen.exitonclick()
```

Turtles at work:

[image]

Finished drawing:

[image]

Comment: I like doing math, but your solution doing this via turtle is funny.

Answer (score 0):

thanks to cdlane, I took his code and put some functionality into functions to make it a Little clearer (at least for me)

```
# -*- coding: cp1252 -*-
import turtle
from turtle import Turtle, Screen
from random import seed, randint

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 640, 480
def create_screen(width, height):
    screen = Screen()
    screen.setup(width * 1.25, height * 1.25)
    return screen

def create_points(count,width = WIDTH, height = HEIGHT):
    vertices = []

    for _ in range(count):
        x = randint(-width//2, width//2)
        y = randint(-height//2, height//2)
        vertices.append((x, y))
    return vertices

def create_turtle_at_position(position):
    turtle = Turtle(shape='turtle')
    turtle.hideturtle()
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(position)
    turtle.showturtle()
    turtle.pendown()
    return turtle

def meet_in_the_middle(turtle_1, turtle_2):

    position_2 = turtle_2.position()

    while True:
        turtle_1.setheading(turtle_1.towards(turtle_2))
        turtle_1.forward(1)
        position_1 = turtle_1.position()
        if int(position_1[0]) == int(position_2[0]) and int(position_1[1]) == int(position_2[1]):
            break

        turtle_2.setheading(turtle_2.towards(turtle_1))
        turtle_2.forward(1)
        position_2 = turtle_2.position()
        if int(position_2[0]) == int(position_1[0]) and int(position_2[1]) == int(position_1[1]):
            break

    turtle_1.hideturtle()
    turtle_2.hideturtle()

    return create_turtle_at_position(position_2)

def draw_median(P1st, P2nd, POpposite):
    turtle_AtoB = create_turtle_at_position(P1st)
    turtle_BtoA = create_turtle_at_position(P2nd)
    turtle_AandBmiddle = meet_in_the_middle(turtle_AtoB, turtle_BtoA)
    turtle_AandBmiddle.setheading(turtle_AandBmiddle.towards(POpposite))
    turtle_AandBmiddle.goto(POpposite)
    return turtle_AandBmiddle

seed()

sc = create_screen(WIDTH, HEIGHT)
for _ in range(5):
    sc = create_screen(WIDTH, HEIGHT)
    A, B, C = create_points(3)
    draw_median(A,B,C)
    draw_median(B,C,A)
    draw_median(C,A,B)

sc.exitonclick()
```

Answer (score 0):

mathematical it is the easiest way to calculate this by vector. Let me say you have a triangle ABC and want to draw a line from A to the middle of BC so your vector starts at A and ends on A + AB + 1/2 BC or A + AC + 1/2 CB (vectorial)

```
(ax) + (bx - ax) + 0.5 (cx - bx)
(ay)   (by - ay)       (cy - by)
```

that results in the coordinates for the opposite Point of

```
x = 0.5(cx + bx)
y = 0.5(cy + by)
```